# Get Day of week for week number in php

Tags: php, date, function

How would I go about getting the date of say the 32 Wed of a given year.  Is there an easy way to do this that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is worth noting, that strtotime() accepts ISO week date format (for example "2008-W27-2" is Tuesday of week 27 in 2008), so it can be easily used to get the date of a given week number.

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#84166)

Comment: `var_dump(strtotime("2008-W27-2"));` returns `false` for me on PHP 5.1.6, but works on 5.2.10. `var_dump(strtotime("2008W272"));` (ie. without the dashes) works in both.

Comment: I did not know the ISO week date format.  That does it, should have asked here 2 hours ago.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date("d m Y", strtotime("2010-W32-3"));
```

i think... :p

Edit: W32 is the week number and 3 is the day of the week (1-7)

Or maybe something more complicated like this - its a bit pointless if the above works - but was just thinking of alternatives... I don't know if it would work. :p Just for fun.

```
echo date("d m Y", strtotime("1-1-2010 + 32 Weeks ".date("N", "Wednesday")." Days"));
```

maybe, but now I'm clutching at straws ha. :)

Comment: So to make it any year it would be as easy as `$year = '2010';` and then `strtotime($year."-W32-3")`

Comment: yeah :) `strtotime($year."-W".$week."-".$dayofweek);`